# Learning process of PHP (Framework Symfony, OOP)

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I am starting a new challenge. I am on my way to learn PHP since (I already have good knowledge in HTML CSS), i would like to have you advise in a good procedure of learning this.
To be specific my final goal is to be a very developer in PHP by the end of 2015 and able to work on project on my own and/or with team as freelancer.
I would like to hear from you guys a step by step learning programs which will conduct me to have confirmed knowledge in PHP OOP and Framework Symphony2. As i don't want to skip the stages i'd like your advise :
I have basic understanding of (loop, if/else, function).

I am looking some course (updated) and exercise to push up my level slowly but efficiency. A list of step would be a great start.

Comment: Start by learning OOP. Personally, I don't prefer learning this in PHP. I'd suggest using Java or C# for that.

Comment: Read [php.net](http://www.php.net) from cover to cover; read [phptherightway.com/](http://www.phptherightway.com/) from cover to cover

Comment: this question is off-topic for SO and in any case there are litterally tons of tutorials, resources, books about what you need (updated), just googling a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you ensure that have a solid understanding of generic programming principles before you focus on a specific language. Knowing markup languages like HTML is relatively easy in comparison. When you get to programming, there's a lot more things to consider.

There's plenty of available free resources that should be able to help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. There are lots of resources out there, some easier than others for a beginner.  I would start on something like [code academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) and augment that with resources like [php.net](http://php.net/).

Then when youve covered those tutorials (I would do all the markup stuff like HTML as well) think of a personal project and build it.  Its all very well reading manuals and doing tutorials, but you need a real live project to force you into finding solutions for real debugging issues.  That cant really be taught.

Its worth noting that PHP isnt the only server side language out there, so keep an open mind and be ready to investigate other avenues as you find them.

Bear in mind to be able to hold your own in the industry is very different from being able to handle your personal projects ok.  There are a lot more variables (no pun intended) in industry and the skillset you need to have is often wider.

Good luck with it.